# How programmatically limit download speed on server with Scala and Play

Tags: scala, playframework

All.

I'm working on project with Play framework and Scala. I need ability to limit download speed from my server, but the exact limitation depends on user, so I can't just use "limit_rate" in my nginx front-end server. Any idea or direction for searching are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see, there is nothing that I can see out of the box that will do what you are looking for.

So, the way I would approach this is to take your own version of Play and modify the source so that

- The [HTTP Response object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/mvc/Http.Response.html) contains a limit download rate field, that you can set when you specifically want to limit this value
- Change the [PlayHandler](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/server/PlayHandler.html) class (probably writeChunk), which is responsible for writing the response back to the browser, so that it puts in some level of pausing each second, to make sure that only outputs at the required rate.

There may be a neater solution at the Netty layer, but I took a quick look and could not find anything. I am not a Netty expert however, so it may be worth you taking a look here yourself.

An alternative method would be to implement your own Render method that extends the RenderBinary method, but this limits you to file downloads only, so may not be universally suitable, but would require less coding for a specific scenario, and can be done without having to modify any core play code. An example of a custom Render method can be found in the [PDF module by Nicolas Leroux](http://www.playframework.org/modules/pdf)

Comment: I'm about to do the same but hopefully I have the only place where it's required so I can try pausing right in the Controller's method. I was unsure about performance due to threads keeping, but from the other side such response limitation requires it anyway. I think I will try this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the controller will work, but you will have duplication of code if you try to re-use this elsewhere.

Comment: I know, to use this in the controller is easier to develop, easier to support (no need in own Play patches) and enough for my task, if I need this in future, I will use your solution or may be just make helper method. Any way thanks for help.